# How to style the selector on Menu items?

Tags: android, menuitem, android-theme

Styling overflow item only works on overflow items, not on items on the Menu button (the hardware button)

How do I style the listSelector on these menu items?

Here from menu button:

[image: menu button]

and here from overflow item:

[image: overflow menu]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if that is possible because many famous apps menu items are not styled like FB, Twitter etc .. 
But styling the images used in menu items is possible but the other one I'm not sure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Single menu item
     Set id, icon and Title for each menu item
-->
<item android:id="@+id/menu_bookmark"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_bookmark"
      android:title="Bookmark" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
      android:title="Save" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
      android:title="Search" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
      android:title="Share" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
      android:title="Delete" /> 

<item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
      android:title="Preferences" />
```

check this for the source of the code: [Android Style Menu Items](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/)

Comment: Yeah you're right. Other apps don' t bother trying to style system theme. I'm just asking though..